# How do you apply transformations to all elements in a window of an unbounded Apache Beam pipeline before outputting the window?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm writing a Dataflow pipeline that will read from Google Pub/Sub and write the data to Google Cloud Storage:

```
    pipeline.apply(marketData)
        .apply(ParDo.of(new PubsubMessageToByteArray()))
        .apply(ParDo.of(new ByteArrayToString()))
        .apply(ParDo.of(new StringToMarketData()))
        .apply(ParDo.of(new AddTimestamps()))
        .apply(Window.<MarketData>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(options.getMinutesPerWindow())))
                .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardSeconds(options.getAllowedSecondLateness()))
                .accumulatingFiredPanes())
        .apply(ParDo.of(new MarketDataToCsv()))
        .apply("Write File(s)", TextIO
                .write()
                .to(options.getOutputDirectory())
                .withWindowedWrites()
                .withNumShards(1)
                .withFilenamePolicy(new WindowedFilenamePolicy(outputBaseDirectory))
                .withHeader(csvHeader));

    pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();
```

I want to deduplicate elements and sort elements in the window before outputting the results. This is different from a typical PTransform in that I want the transform to execute once the window ends.

The Pub/Sub topic will have duplicates because multiple workers are producing the same messages in case one worker fails. How do I remove all duplicates within a window before writing? I see that a [RemoveDuplicates](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/0.2.0-incubating/index.html?org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/RemoveDuplicates.WithRepresentativeValues.html) class existed in Beam version 0.2, but not in the current version.

I understand that under the hood, Beam parallelizes the PTransforms across workers. But since this pipeline writes `withNumShards(1)`, only one worker will write the final result. Which means that in theory, it should be possible to have that worker apply a deduplication transform before writing.

The Beam python sdk [still has a RemoveDuplicates method](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/9c1eeb2d7efc65978d189ebc259fad6fbe2176ce/sdks/python/apache_beam/transforms/util.py), so I can reproduce that logic in Java, but why would it have been removed unless there's a better way? I'd imagine the implementation would be a deduplication ParDo that was executed after some window trigger.

EDIT: [GroupByKey](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.2.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/GroupByKey.html) and [SortValues](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.2.0/) look like they'll do what I need. I'm attempting to use those now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an answer for the deduplication part:

```
.apply(Distinct
 // MarketData::key produces a String. Use withRepresentativeValue() 
 // because Apache beam deserializes Java objects into bytes, which 
 // could cause two equal objects to be interpreted as not equal. See 
 // org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Distinct.java for details. 
 .withRepresentativeValueFn(MarketData::key)
 .withRepresentativeType(TypeDescriptor.of(String.class)))
```

And here's a solution for sorting and deduplicating elements (in case sorting is needed also):

```
public static class DedupAndSortByTime extends 
        Combine.CombineFn<MarketData, TreeSet<MarketData>, List<MarketData>> {
    @Override
    public TreeSet<MarketData> createAccumulator() {
        return new TreeSet<>(Comparator
                .comparingLong(MarketData::getEventTime)
                .thenComparing(MarketData::getOrderbookType));
    }

    @Override
    public TreeSet<MarketData> addInput(TreeSet<MarketData> accum, MarketData input) {
        accum.add(input);
        return accum;
    }

    @Override
    public TreeSet<MarketData> mergeAccumulators(Iterable<TreeSet<MarketData>> accums) {

        TreeSet<MarketData> merged = createAccumulator();
        for (TreeSet<MarketData> accum : accums) {
            merged.addAll(accum);
        }
        return merged;
    }

    @Override
    public List<MarketData> extractOutput(TreeSet<MarketData> accum) {
        return Lists.newArrayList(accum.iterator());
    }
}
```

So the updated pipeline is

```
    // Pipeline
    pipeline.apply(marketData)
        .apply(ParDo.of(new MarketDataDoFns.PubsubMessageToByteArray()))
        .apply(ParDo.of(new MarketDataDoFns.ByteArrayToString()))
        .apply(ParDo.of(new MarketDataDoFns.StringToMarketDataAggregate()))
        .apply(ParDo.of(new MarketDataDoFns.DenormalizeMarketDataAggregate()))
        .apply(ParDo.of(new MarketDataDoFns.AddTimestamps()))
        .apply(Window.<MarketData>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(options.getMinutesPerWindow())))
                .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardSeconds(options.getAllowedSecondLateness()))
                .accumulatingFiredPanes())
        .apply(Combine.globally(new MarketDataCombineFn.DedupAndSortByTime()).withoutDefaults())
        .apply(ParDo.of(new MarketDataDoFns.MarketDataToCsv()))
        .apply("Write File(s)", TextIO
                .write()
                // This doesn't set the output directory as expected. 
                // "/output" gets stripped and I don't know why,
                // so "/output" has to be added to the directory path 
                // within the FilenamePolicy.
                .to(options.getOutputDirectory())
                .withWindowedWrites()
                .withNumShards(1)
                .withFilenamePolicy(new MarketDataFilenamePolicy.WindowedFilenamePolicy(outputBaseDirectory))
                .withHeader(csvHeader));

    pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();
```